# Skill clone failed. Reason: Command failed: git branch --show-current

Tags: git, alexa-skills-kit

I am getting this error while cloning the code from the Alexa Developer console on Ubuntu.

`Skill clone failed. Reason: Command failed: git branch --show-current`

[image: Skill clone failed]

Could anyone please let me what I have to do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind trying this using a different OS? I recommend you to post your issue in Github https://github.com/alexa/ask-cli/issues/, I found a pretty similar issue https://github.com/alexa/ask-cli/issues/286 that the users managed to resolve. I hope this helps you.